# How to have Ruby on Rails watch for inserted records on a postgresql table that is shared with another app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql

I have an app using Rails 6.1 with a postgres db. A second app has access to the same database and inserts records to one of the tables there. I want the Rails app to know when new records are inserted so I can run some Ruby code in response. I’m trying to find a robust, testable solution. The best idea I can come up with is to add a boolean column on that table. Then have the Rails app periodically query the table for any records with the new column set to false, run the code for those records, and then flip the new column to true. It would mean using something like the Whenever gem. I can’t think of any better idea. I looked into pubsub type stuff with postgres using listen and notify and it didn’t feel like that was going to be as robust and testable.  Sadly, creating an API endpoint in the Rails app is not an option.

Comment: Why is setting up a simple webhook on the app that needs to be notified out of the question?

Comment: Two application using a shared database feel like a bad practice to me that can lead to issues. Instead, I would suggest the second application not adding those records directly into the database, but instead passing them to an API endpoint of the first app. Then the first app takes care of writing the records into the database and doing whatever it needs to do with those records.

Comment: Thanks for your replies. The specifications of the assignment prevent me from adding an API endpoint.  Yes, I agree it is a bad practice to have a shared database, but sadly, that's the situation and I can't change it.

Answer (score 1):

If an API endpoint really isn't an option, we can still use some of the same techniques if the non-Rails app inserts into a different table.

Let's call the table `products`, with a matching `Product` model. This is the products table that the Rails app uses. We'll call this AppOne.

Let's call the other app AppTwo. It will insert into a table called `app_two_products`. This is nice as the other app doesn't have to care about Rails columns like `created_at` etc, and you can change your `products` table and `Product` model in AppOne without breaking AppTwo's insert code. I'd really recommend against letting both apps access the same table If AppTwo decides to bulk import 1 million records, that could break forms in AppOne. If AppTwo has full access to AppOne's table it could even end up deleting records. We want to control when and how this stuff is ingested.

We now write some code in AppOne to transform the data in `app_two_products` into `products`. As `products` has an ActiveRecord Product model, we have all the benefits associated with that (eg validations, callbacks). I'd recommend [Kiba](https://github.com/thbar/kiba), an ETL Gem, for this kind of code, but you could also just write a regular Ruby script/object. The Ruby code that needs to be run after insert could be done on the ActiveRecord object or via the import script. You can use Sidekiq and [Sidekiq Cron](https://github.com/sidekiq-cron/sidekiq-cron) to regularly run this import script, or indeed Whenever as suggested.

I'm assuming here that it doesn't matter if data is "late" into your app, and any insert from AppTwo doesn't need to be reflected instantly. IME this is often the case. If there are times when it needs to be "rushed", you could add a "Import now" button that triggers the job.

Again, I'd highly discourage having both of these apps working on the same table. If AppTwo *has* to insert into the table that AppOne is using, I would change the table AppOne is using to avoid them using the same table.